# PlatformIO Toolbar not showing up in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, esp8266, platformio

As seen in the picture: I have PIO installed and active, but it don't shows it's toolbar for uploading the project. Yesterday a simple restart of VSCode fixed it, today nothing changed after a lot of restarts. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc63R.png]

Comment: so after the 14th ragereboot or so it out of the blue showed up again, I have no clue.
And it'll definitely disappear in one of the next starts again.

Comment: Post the code as text, not as image.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt The point is not the code, its the absence of the sidebar ._.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes upon this.  I had a similar problem.  It is more a workaround than a solution.  (I'm running VSCode on Ubuntu)

> 1. {ctrl+alt+t}   #Open a terminal
> 2. $ cd {folder location}   #Change directory to the location where your src folder and platformio.ini file is located
> 3. $ code .   #Launch VSCode from the terminal window

My icon to upload and launch serial monitor now show on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem sometimes.

For me, the best solution is to disable the extension globally (for all projects) in the extension's settings. Then I trigger a reload.

Afterwards I enable it again, if my project is already open, it will recreate the Platform IO sidebar. Classic case of "Have you tried turning it off and on again?".